Artifact in MEMS microphone after loud, impulsive sounds
I have made a recording using a MEMS microphone and I noticed that when I have a series of very loud, close-to-mic, events (such as clapping - see the figure), then any normal sound that follows these events, like speech, laughing, coughing, etc., is not properly recorded by the mic. What the mic records is shown in red arrows.
I understand that this is due to the mic's attempt to handle its input after these pretty loud events, but does anyone know what this is, how it's called, why it happens, and how can someone control it (either in real-time or post-recording)?


I am experiencing similar issues. Did you find a way to solve it? What kind of microphone did you use (analog/digital PDM/I2S)?

@MarkusLempenML this is the microphone (https://www.lcsc.com/datasheet/lcsc_datasheet_2101041805_MEMS-MSM261D3526Z1CM_C966937.pdf). No, I can't really find a solution. From the answers, I understand what's wrong but it's beyond my control to fix it. I just accept it, it does not hurt that much in my case after all.


does anyone know what this is, how it's called,

From Hilmar's answer, apparently it's called "acoustic overload", at least if it happens in the mic.  "Saturation" is another term that may apply more generally, "railed" is circuit-designer slang for a signal that's hit a power supply voltage (i.e., power supply rail).
It looks like whatever is hitting a rail has a bias system that's trying to keep it centered in its operating range.  When it hits a rail, that drags the bias in a direction that makes the output high, or it injects a charge into some AC-coupling capacitor.  That exponential decay that you're seeing is either the bias adjusting itself, or that AC-coupled stage in the audio chain relaxing.

why it happens,

This is part of a wider phenomenon.  The most general effect is that any time mankind tries to build a linear system, they end up building a system that's linear within limits, and outside of those limits the system misbehaves.
I don't know why it happens in MEMS microphones, but it's a microphone, so someplace deep inside the thing there's an element that moves within limits, and if it gets exposed to sound levels above what it's designed for it'll hit those limits and work differently.  In some systems (from Hilmar's answer it sounds like MEMS microphones currently fall into this class) when you hit those limits it can damage the device.  In other systems the device is, either intrinsically or by design, arranged so that the limits can be reached without damaging anything.
It sounds like you're using off the shelf components, so there's a possibility that what you're seeing isn't the microphone element itself hitting a rail, but possibly some other stage in the signal processing chain.  If you are just buying stuff and using it then you can't really go much further than knowing that the system has some part that's hitting a rail.
If I were designing a device that used a MEMS, and I ran into this phenomenon, I'd probably be at a bench with an oscilloscope right now, irritating my coworkers or family by clapping my hands while trying to figure out if it's the microphone itself or some succeeding audio stage that's the culprit.

and how can someone control it


Don't let the microphone see impulsive noises like that.

Move it away from the hands.
Muffle it, and turn up the gain at the recording end.  Yes, this will increase your noise.  This is life, welcome to it.


Choose a microphone technology that is more tolerant of impulsive noises.
If you're the circuit designer for the whole system, break out the o-scope, go to the lab, and start irritating your coworkers or family by clapping into the microphone while making sure that it's the mic element and not some following stage that's doing that.
If it's all purchased parts but you have control over the audio chain, try fiddling with gains in the entire system -- on the theory that maybe it's some other stage and not the mic.  If, for instance, you attenuate between the mic and the preamp, and turn up the master gain and the problem goes away or happens later -- congratulations, it's the preamp.  Keep swapping parts until you're exhausted, or until the system is working well.


Great answer, thanks! I would assume it's not the mic that drives these results. I have two devices (smartwatches made by different manufacturers) that have the exact same microphone, according to their specs. However, the other device produces much less of these artifacts - and the waveform recorded is somewhat different when it comes to loud sounds (normal speech looks the same on both). I guess that means it's another component of the pipeline that is responsible for this effect, right?

Unless the microphone in question has some sort of bias setting or loud vs. quiet pin, yes, if you see a substantive difference between two signal chains, then it's probably a difference outside of the microphone.

Yes, it's this one: https://www.lcsc.com/datasheet/lcsc_datasheet_2101041805_MEMS-MSM261D3526Z1CM_C966937.pdf
I don't see anything related.

For starters, it's generally not a good idea to operate a MEMS microphone at sound pressure levels above their Acoustic Overload Point (AOP). While they can recover from some amount of overload, they can take permanent physical damage when things get too loud and they are sensitive specifically to peaks (not RMS) so impulsive noise can be dangerous even if the SPL that shows up on a meter (which has a longish time constant) isn't all that high.
There are various different blocks in the chain: microphone, internal preamp, power supply, input amp, ADC, etc. Each of those has different overload behaviors and it's kind a hard to tell which is the weakest link without deep diving into each one individually.
This being said, there is clearly a time constant associated with the behavior. Unfortunately the axes of your graph are not labelled so I can't tell what it is. My best guess is that the overload pulls down the supply or bias voltage and it takes a bit for the power supply to move it back again. I would look at the schematic and identify any capacitors whose value is on the right ballpark.

Thanks for giving some terminology and for your reply in general. I completely understand that this is not appropriate behavior but it might happen if this microphone is embedded to some device that can be widely used without supervision, like a smartwatch.

Mems microphones have a back cavity behind the diaphragm which is vented to the outside world through a tiny laser-drilled hole.  It is this hole that causes the microphone to roll off below a certain frequency.  A loud low-frequency impulsive sound can cause pressure to build up in the back cavity, which displaces the diaphragm for a period of time until it equalizes.  There are also mechanisms in the preamp that involve how the bias is set; the MEMs element is purely capacitive and must be biased with a very large resistor to avoid rolling off the low end.  A large low-frequency signal may cause the MEMs element to encounter some electrical non-linearity which shifts the bias point. The recovery from this shift may take a long time, and the preamp may be clipped while it recovers.
In the automotive audio industry, where MEMs mics are used inside the cabin, this effect is known as the “door-slam effect”. When a car door closes quickly the entire pressure inside the cabin is increased for some period of time.

https://www.analog.com/en/resources/analog-dialogue/articles/using-sigma-delta-converters-2.html
Perhaps it is an issue similar to this:
"Q: What happens if my input signal is beyond the input range of the sigma-delta converter? I remember hearing something about the converter becoming unstable?
A: The modulator can become temporarily unstable if it is driven with inputs outside the recommended range. However, this instability is invisible to the user, since decimators are generally designed to simply clip the digital output and show either negative or positive full scale, just as one would expect with a conventional converter."
